# Azure Service Bus - MessageCommunication Exception Channel Open timeout

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am new to Azure Service Bus.

I am trying to add message to Azure Service Bus Queue like below

```
var message = new BrokeredMessage() { Label = inputFileEntity.FileName };                
message.MessageId = new Guid().ToString();
message.Properties.Add("FilePath", inputFileEntity.FilePath);

// submit the file for injector
QueueConnector.InputFileQueueClient.Send(message);
```

I am getting MessageCommunication Exception as below

```
Channel Open did not complete within the specified timeout of 00:01:00
```

When I am initializing QueueClient I even configured operation timeout value to 10 minutes, still same issue

```
 var namespaceManager = CreateNamespaceManager();
 namespaceManager.Settings.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
```

Where I am going wrong, any direction or pointers will be of great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This generally indicates a networking issue, in that there may be a firewall blocking outbound communication on TCP ports needed. You can also set the connectivity mode to http and send traffic over port 80.

```
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http;
```